# Как сравнить 2 массива объектов на полную идентичность (порядок расположения элементов роли не играет)

Tags: javascript

Имеется 2 массива объектов вида

```
arr1 = [{a: 1, b: 2}, {a: 15, b: 4}, {a: 12, b: 7}];
arr2 = [{a: 15, b: 4}, {a: 1, b: 2}, {a: 12, b: 7}];
```

Эти 2 массива должны быть идентичны (даже несмотря на то, что объекты расположены в разном порядке).

А эти 2 массива

```
arr1 = [{a: 1, b: 2}, {a: 15, b: 4}, {a: 12, b: 7}];
arr2 = [{a: 15, b: 4}, {a: 1, b: 3}, {a: 12, b: 7}];
```

уже не должны быть одинаковы (b = 3).

В идеале стоило бы использовать какой-нибудь встроенный метод вроде `Array.prototype.equals()`, который, к сожалению, спецификация ECMAScript нам успешненько зажала. По сути, его я реализовать и пытаюсь.

Мои размышления по этому поводу привели к тому, что для начала эти 2 массива стоит отсортировать. **Именно в этом у меня и возникли трудности** (вполне возможно, что вопрос стоило назвать как-нибудь вроде *"Как отсортировать массив объектов"*, так что, если стоит так и сделать, скажите об этом). MDN приводит нам в справку, что нужно делать примерно так:

```
arr.sort((obj1, obj2) => {
    return *???*
});
```

И тут в строчке с `return` написано что-то вроде `obj1 - obj2`. Но сами объекты друг от друга отнимать нельзя, нужно сравнивать их свойства. Но **как сравнить больше одного** свойства - в упор **не понимаю**. Да и в принципе вообще не понимаю, как происходит это магическое `a - b` (в [примере на MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)). Поэтому прошу помочь реализовать сортировку массива, состоящего из объектов по двум свойствам этого объекта. Остальная часть реализации сравнения, по крайней мере пока, кажется очевидной.

UPDATE:
Да, свойства `a` и `b`, по которым нужно проводить сортировку, могут иметь в себе только целые числа.

Comment: "как сравнить больше одного свойства" - по очереди, естественно. Сравниваете `а`, если они равны, сравниваете `b`, и т.д.

Comment: @Igor но там в примере это значение возвращается. Если я верну результат сравнения `a`, то до проверки `b` дело уже и не дойдет.

Comment: так какой все-таки вопрос? как сравнить или как отсортировать?

Comment: @Grundy  вопрос - как сравнивать (может есть варианты получше моего). Но застрял я на сортировке (может быть зря, может быть она там и не нужна вовсе).

Comment: поля объектов только числа? все объекты имеют одинаковый набор полей?

Comment: @Grundy те, что нужно сравнить - да. И да, одинаковый.

Comment: что значит, те что нужно сравнить? в объектах есть и другие свойства? Список свойств которые нужно сравнить известен заранее?

Comment: @Grundy да, сравнивать нужно только по свойствам `a` и `b`. Но есть и куча других.

Comment: Хотя подождите, именно сравниваться они будут по свойству C. Но, я думаю, отсортировать их по свойству a и b будет достаточно.

Comment: @Igor подойду более частно к ответу. a и b - это x и y клетки (игра "сапер"). c - имеет ли клетка мину. Проверяю, выиграл ли игрок. Отсортировав по иксу и игрику буду уверен, что они в определенном порядке находятся. Дальше сравниваю массив закрытых клеток с массивом клеток с минами (то есть по св-ву `c`). Если одинаковы - значит игрок выиграл.

Comment: @Igor а я и не говорю, что ваше решение нерабочее. Никогда не отмечаю ответ решением сразу после того, как он был дан. Мало ли кто-нибудь лучше предложит. А ваш вариант далеко не идеал. И почему не надо про мины? Я просто для конкретики их ввел, чтобы лучше представлять, о чем речь идет. Вопрос ведь в том, как сравнить 2 массива (один - клетки с минами, другой - закрытые клетки). А застрял я на сортировке, да, признаю.

Comment: @Igor сортировка и сравнение ведь 2 разных действия. Сортировать я могу по чему угодно, и это не значит, что сравнивать я их по этим же критериям буду. Просто Grundy спросил, есть ли свойства еще.

Comment: @Grundy перечитал комментарии и понял, что ошибся. Я должен **сравнить** объекты *целиком*. На полную идентичность. А для этого, как я понимаю, их нужно сначала отсортировать. И **сортировки** по a и b будет достаточно.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56066/discussion-between-grundy-and-smellyshovel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Сначала проверяешь массивы на кол-во элементов. Если кол-во элементов одинаковое, то идешь к пункту 2, а иначе возвращается false.
2. Берешь элемент первого массива и пытаешься его найти во втором. Если его нету, то возвращаешь false, в противном случае извлекаешь очередной элемент из первого массива.